# How to prompt "su" to re-request a password on an incorrect entry?

Tags: linux, security, sudo, pam, su

Default `su` behaviour :

```
system@sword:/etc/pam.d$ su - test
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
<su exits>
```

I need to configure "delay" when someone enters an incorrect password for dictionary attack prevention of my system. To test this configuration, I want to configure `su` using `PAM` in ubuntu to achieve such a behavior :

```
system@sword:/etc/pam.d$ su - test
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
<delay for "y" seconds>
<re-asks password>
Password: 
su: Authentication failure
<delay for "y" seconds>
<su exits>
```

How do I achieve this using `PAM`, or by any other means if necessary ?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest solution would be to (depending on your distro) modify `/etc/default/su` or `/etc/login.defs` and set `FAIL_DELAY N` where `N` is a positive integer number (seconds).

That won't make `su` prompt repeatedly, but it will enforce a wait of `N` seconds before it returns to the shell.

Of course that won't stop people from using `Ctrl-C` to terminate `su` prematurely.

You can achieve the same result via PAM by editing
`/etc/pam.d/su` and adding the line

```
auth       optional   pam_faildelay.so  delay=3000000
```

near the top of the file (before other `auth     required` settings).